# How to authenticate users with an integer such as account number as the username

Tags: django-authentication

I have a problem authenticating users in my banking application. I want super users to be created and authenticated using email. However, I want that normal users be registered and assigned account numbers. The normal users would then use the account numbers to login. How do you achieve authentication of these different kinds of users with different username fields in one django project.

I have tried overriding the USERNAME_FIELD to account numbers so that normal users would use that to login. It doesnt help to login normal users. For superusers, it prompts for account number when I run 
python manage.py createsuperuser
Kindly assist in understanding how to handle this kind of custom authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Django is ready to support your requirement. `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` support multiple backend as list. For normal user you have to write custom backend and Add that in `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`.

This [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend) will help you.